# Remember an class option with newcommand and CurrentOption

Tags: document-classes, optional-arguments, class-options, options

I'm trying to make a class but it needs to remember its arguments

I'm using the file

```
\documentclass[x]{test}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

With the class

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/01/15 test class]

\DeclareOption*{
  \newcommand{\test}{y}
  \typeout{\test}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\typeout{\test}

\endinput
```

It outputs

```
 y
 y
```

which is good but that's not what I want to do.

With the class

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/01/15 test class]

\DeclareOption*{
  \newcommand{\test}{\CurrentOption}
  \typeout{\test}
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\typeout{\test}

\endinput
```

I get

```
x
<- empty line
```

It like it does not "dereference" `\CurrentOption` and take its string value so for the second `\typeout`, `\CurrentOption` is not defined to anything anymore and I get an empty value :(
Does anyone know how to "dereference" it ? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\let` to make `\test` have the definition of `\CurrentOption` rather than reference it:

```
\documentclass[jjj]{test}

\stop
```

with class

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}[2015/01/15 test class]

\DeclareOption*{%
  \let\test\CurrentOption
  \typeout{\test}%
}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\typeout{\test}

\endinput
```

Comment: I had tried with `\def` but not with `\let`, you saved my day :)